# jQuery: onClick not reusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to

- get my navbar dropdowns to open on mouse enter when the screen is > 992px
- and for the dropdown to open on click when the screen is smaller than 992px.

The issue I am having is that it works fine the first time, but after I click the dropdown heading a second time and it closes, I am unable to open it after it closes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function windowSizeCheck() {
    var $windowSize = $(window).width();
    if ($windowSize > 992) {
      $('.dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').stop(true).slideUp('fast');
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
        });
      });
    } else {
      $('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).css({
          'max-height': '400px',
          'overflow-y': 'auto'
        })

        $(this).on('click', function() {
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').stop(true).slideUp('fast');
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
        });
      });
    }
  }
  windowSizeCheck();
});
```

```css
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white px-2 py-0 shadow-sm fixed-top">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
  <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase active navOp">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Brands</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0 ">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Gucci</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Versace</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Louis Vuitton</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Michael Kors</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shoes</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Women</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Bags</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">Shoulder Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Mini Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Travel Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Handbags</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Tops</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shirts</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweaters</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Hoodies</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jackets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Pants</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Denim</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Leggings</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Skirts</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shorts</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Accessories</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Purses/ Wallets</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sunglasses </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shoes </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Men</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0 text-center">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Tops</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">Tees</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Crewnecks</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweaters</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jackets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Pants</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Street-wear</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jeans</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweats</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Joggers</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Shoes</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sneakers</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Boots</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Skate Shoes</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Street-wear</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Accessories</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Wallets</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sunglasses</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navOp"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item navOp"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made you a proper snippet

Comment: Thank you! I am new and was unsure how exactly to get the snippit to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- you were detecting the screen size on document load only, added a window resize event to recalculate the `$windowSize` value
- changed the inline `max-height` and `overflow-y` properties to a class `openNav`
- there was an inline `display:block` property which got added and restricted the nav to close on click (on < 992px)
- going from desktop to mobile version, we would have to 'unbind' the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events also

Working **code snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function windowSizeCheck() {
    var $windowSize = $(window).width();

    if ($windowSize > 992) {
      $('.dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').addClass('open');

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').stop(true).slideUp('fast');
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
        });
      });
    } else {

      $('.dropdown').unbind("mouseenter");
      $('.dropdown').unbind("mouseleave");

      $('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggleClass('openNav');

        if ($(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').hasClass('open')) {
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
        }
        if ($(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').attr('style')) {
          $(this).children('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');
        }

      });
    }
  }
  // this runs when document loads for the first time
  windowSizeCheck();

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    // this runs when document loads for the first time
    windowSizeCheck();
  });

});
```

```css
.open {
  display: block;
}

.openNav {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu{
min-width: max-content !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.dropdown-menu{
min-width: 10rem !important;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white px-2 py-0 shadow-sm fixed-top">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase active navOp">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Brands</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0 ">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Gucci</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Versace</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Louis Vuitton</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Women</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">For Men</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Accessories </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Featured</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Michael Kors</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shoes</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Women</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Bags</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">Shoulder Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Mini Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Travel Bags</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Handbags</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Tops</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shirts</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweaters</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Hoodies</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jackets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Pants</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Denim</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Leggings</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Skirts</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shorts</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Accessories</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Purses/ Wallets</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sunglasses </a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Shoes </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown megamenu navOp"><a id="megamneu" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase">Men</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="megamneu" class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0 text-center">
          <div class="p-4 container justify-content-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Tops</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0">Tees</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Crewnecks</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweaters</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jackets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Pants</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Street-wear</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jeans</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sweats</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Joggers</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Shoes</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sneakers</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Boots</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Skate Shoes</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Street-wear</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">Accessories</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Wallets</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Watches</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Jewelry</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-small pb-0 ">Sunglasses</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navOp"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item navOp"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're welcome... Pleas accept the answer so that other can benefit from it in the future also